# Does reverted transactions considered as mined transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, revert-opcode

I want to know if a reverted transaction is considered as mined one ?

this is mean nonce should be incremented

Comment: Why don't you check it and find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transaction can't revert unless it's mined. This is because miners are the ones who actually execute the transaction. Furthermore a reverted transaction is a valid transaction so it's a regular transaction which just didn't succeed and was rolled back.

So yes you have to increase your nonce.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Truffle test to prove that it does:

**Contract File:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25; 

contract MyContract {
    uint x;
    function func(uint _x) public {
        require(x != _x);
        x = _x;
    }
}
```

**Test File:**

```
contract("test", function(accounts) {
    it("test", async function() {
        await printNonce(accounts[0]);
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new({from: accounts[0]});
        await printNonce(accounts[0]);
        await myContract.func(1, {from: accounts[0]});
        try {
            await printNonce(accounts[0]);
            await myContract.func(1, {from: accounts[0]});
            throw null;
        }
        catch (error) {
            assert(error && error.message.startsWith("VM Exception"));
        }
        await printNonce(accounts[0]);
        await myContract.func(2, {from: accounts[0]});
        await printNonce(accounts[0]);
    });
});

async function printNonce(account) {
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account);
    console.log(nonce);
}
```

**Printout:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
```